# Understanding the proof - Homotopy topology

Tags: general-topology

If $h: (X,x_0) \to (Y_, y_0)$ is a homeormorphism of $X$ with $Y$, then $h_*$ is an isomorphism of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ and $\pi_1 (Y, y_0)$.

Here is how the proof goes :

Let $k : (Y,y_0) \to (X, x_0)$ be the continuous inverse (since $h$ is a homeomorphism this exists), then $k_* \mathcal{o} \ h_* = (k\ \mathcal{o} \ h)_* = i_*$. Here, $i_*$ is the identity homomorphism of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$. Also note that $h_* \mathcal{o} \ k_* = (h \mathcal{o} k)_* = j_*$ where $j$ is the identity homomorphism of $\pi_2(Y,y_0)$

**I understood everything up to this point. $i_*$ and $j_*$ are homomorphisms. However**

Then $k_*$ is the inverse of $h_*$.

**This is the end of the proof. So basically we have proved that $k_*$ is both a right and left inverse of $h_*$, and then is a inverse of $h_*$ making it an isomorphism. The part I didn't get is, how do we conclude that it's a right and left inverse? Does $i_*$ and $j_*$ needs to homomorphisms?Can you guys give me more of a rigorous argument? thanks.**

Comment: Maybe your notation is making things confusing. $i_*$ is the group homomorphism $id:\pi_1(X,x_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(X,x_0)$ induced by the identity map $i: X \rightarrow X$. So basically you proved that $k_* \circ h_* = id_{\pi_1(X,x_0)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little irritated about what you didn't get, so i start a little bit earlier.

A homomorphism between groups is called an **isomorphism** if it's bijective.

A homomorphism $f: G \to H$ between groups is an isomorphism if and only if there exists some homomorphism $g: H \to G$, s.t. $g \circ h = \text{id}_{G}$ and $h \circ g = \text{id}_H$.

This is easy to verify and thats what you just have shown for $h_*$:

$$h_* : \pi_1(X,x_0) \to \pi_1(Y,y_0)$$ is an isomorphism since there is some $$k_*: \pi_1(Y,y_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_0),$$

such that $h_* \circ k_* = \text{id}_{\pi_1(Y,y_0)}$ and $k_* \circ h_* = \text{id}_{\pi_1(X,x_0)}$ holds, thus $h_*$ and especially $k_*$ are isomorphisms.

But why does it hold $h_* \circ k_* = \text{id}_{\pi_1(Y,y_0)}$? As you maybe in lecture have shown it holds $h_* \circ k_* = (h \circ k)_*$. How does the map $(h \circ k)$ behave?

Since $h$ and $k$ are assumed to be continuous, $h \circ k$ is continuous too. But they are inverse to each other too as they are inverse homeomorphisms, thus $h \circ k$ is just the identity map on the topological space $Y$.

The induced homomorphism $f_*:\pi_1(Y,y_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_0)$ to a continuous map $f: (Y,y_0) \to (X,x_0)$ is defined by

$$f_*([\alpha]) := [f \circ \alpha],$$

where $\alpha$ is just a path in $y$. So as $h \circ k$ is the identity on $Y$ it holds

$$(h \circ k) \circ \alpha = \alpha \text{ for all paths } \alpha \text{ in } Y,$$

thus it holds $(h \circ k)_*([\alpha]) = [(h \circ k) \circ \alpha] = [\alpha]$ for all $[\alpha] \in \pi_1(Y,y_0)$.

In other words $(h \circ k)_*$ is just the identity on $\pi$. The same arguments work for $(k \circ h)_* = \text{id}_{\pi_1(X,x_0)}$.

Comment: As an aside, the general definition of "isomorphism" is the latter one -- a homomorphism that has an inverse homomorphism. It's a peculiar property of groups (and sets) that a bijection happens to be an isomorphism.